# How do I create a matrix of non-repeating random numbers with numpy, while having a range between these random numbers?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, random

This line of code already create a 3x3 matrix populated with random numbers between 0 and 8, but some of them are duplicated. How to stop this?

```
initStateRandom = np.random.randint(9, size=(3,3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `choice` function from `np.random`, see the [documentation](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html). 
You can either pass in an int for the range or any ndarray.

```py
import numpy as np

r_array = np.random.choice(9, size=(3, 3), replace=False)  # int
r_array = np.random.choice(np.arange(10, 100), size=(3, 3), replace=False)  # ndarray
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 'np.random.shuffle'.  It works in-place, and only along one dimension for multi-dimensional arrays, so you'd need to shuffle a temporary 1-d array like this:

```
    import numpy as np

    tmp=np.arange(9)
    np.random.shuffle(tmp)
    mat=np.reshape(tmp,[3,3])
```